# How can I update an arrayList that contains multiple values?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a basket that stores into an arraylist (Item key, qty and the price of the item). How can I update just the quantity and not create another line with the same Item key.
Here is the outcome that the program below does.

```
Java Book                 1   £48.90

Samsung Galaxy S7         1   £639.50


Speakers                  3   £59.80


Java Book                 2   £48.90


Samsung Galaxy S7         2   £639.50
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private void ItemsBasket(String name, int qty, String key) throws HeadlessException {

        if (name == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Selecet a key");
            String imageFileName = "./images/" + key + ".png";
            File imageFile = new File(imageFileName);

            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                imageFileName = "./images/empty.png";
            }

        } else if (qty <= StockData.getQuantity(key)) {


            arList.add(StockData.getName(key) + "\t\t  " + qty + "   " + pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(key)));

            bagtotal += StockData.getPrice(key) * qty;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sucessfully added to the basket");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insuffcient stock");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Available items qty : " + "**" + StockData.getQuantity(key) + "**");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain "How can I update just the quantity and not to create another line with the same Item key?" in a different way? I think most of us are having a hard time understanding this.

Comment: so the code gets data from a database that use a key to retrieve its values. in this case per example Java Book, Speakers etc. so when i choose the key a qty  to add to the basket it stores the name of the key and the qty entered. My problem is that if choose the same product again it just adds a new line to the arraylist rather that just updating the qty. Hope it make sense now

Answer (score 5):

Create a `StockData` object and add it directly to the `ArrayList<StockData>`

```
public class StockData{
    String name;
    int qty;
    double price;

    public StockData(String n, int q, double p){
    // Initialization
    }
}
```

Then, using a setter, you can modify the data for the objects within your `List`

```
arList.get(index).setName("NewName");
```

Comment: Yeah, Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it! +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using an `ArrayList<String>`, but rather a more specialized structure.

The `StockData` object of @YassinHajaj is a good start (but I will instead use `BasketItem`, which is more descriptive).

But java allows us to do even better: you can use a `Map` `Map<String, BasketItem> basket = new HashMap<String, BasketItem>()`.

This way you can make an updateBasketItem method:

```
private void addToOrUpdateBasketItem(String key, int qty) {
    BasketItem item = basket.getKey(key);
    if (item == null){
        item = new BasketItem(StockData.getName(key), qty, pounds.format(StockData.getPrice(key)));
        basket.put(key, item);
    } else {
        item.increaseWithQuantity(qty);
    }
}
```